# Preview images with AJAX image upload

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, file-upload

I have created an ajax image upload system. When the user selects the image he wants to upload, the image is checked for security reasons and then uploaded to a file folder. The image is then displayed through the path of that file folder on ajax callback. The problem is that I want the image to be uploaded to the file AFTER the user has clicked a button. This would force me to rely on the temporary path file of the image, `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` as the source of the image to be displayed. However, that doesn't work.

My question is this. If I can't use the temporary file path as the image source for the uploaded image, what would be my other options? I guess I could when the submit button is clicked move the file AGAIN and delete the old image, but there is the possibility the user might upload the file, exit the browser, and leave the image in the folder forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a temp directory and move the uploaded file there, then if the user does not want to upload it after he see the preview you delete the image. You can't use the php's temp file because it lasts until the script finished it's execution.

Comment: How would I avoid then those chances where the user will exit from the browser before deciding whether or not to keep the image?

Comment: Have the user to be logged in to upload an image?

Comment: Let me explain it a different way. You are logged in my site. You pick an image you want to upload to my site. You are previewed the image. You don't like it so you exit the browser. The image is still in the temporary directory and won't be deleted, since you simply exited the browswer.

Comment: Ok, you could try this. When moving your files in your temp dir, give them as a name the current_timestamp. Now each time anyone loads the script you will check if there are any file in your temp dir. If there are, you take each file's name (that is exactly the time that it has been created) and compaire it with the current_timestamp. If it has been created more than xx minutes ago you remove the file otherwise you dont do anything.